# Angular reflects global variable changes to local variable of a function

Tags: html, angular, typescript, two-way-binding

I am facing a problem while using ngx-bootstrap modal. 
I have a table in html, that using edit icon to open an edit modal with prefilled value of table column in input. Like that.

```
<tr *ngFor="let cat of categories; let i = index">
            <th>{{i+1}}</th>
            <td>{{cat.name}}</td>
            <td>
              <fa-icon
                class="is-icon text-primary mr-2"
                [icon]="faEdit"
                (click)="openModal(updateCategory, cat);">
              </fa-icon>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

The openModal() will set cat to category variable in my component. like this.

```
openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>, category?: Category) {
    if (category){
      this.category = category;
    }

    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.modalService.onHide.subscribe(() => {
        this.category = {} as Category;
        console.log(this.category);
        this.category = category;
        console.log(this.category, category);
        this.unsubscribe();
      })
    );

    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, this.modalConfig);
  }
```

The component's category variable is used in modalTemplate to render prefilled text in input like this

```
<ng-template #updateCategory>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Update category</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form #updateCategoryForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="update(updateCategoryForm); loading = true">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input
          required
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="New name"
          name="updateCategory"
          #updateCategory="ngModel"
          [(ngModel)]="category.name"
          [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': updateCategory.invalid && updateCategory.touched}">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Category name is required.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center">
        <button
          class="btn btn-primary"
          type="submit"
          [disabled]="!updateCategoryForm.valid">
                  <span
                    class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"
                    *ngIf="loading"></span>
          Update
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Now the problem is when i make a change in input, category of component updates because i am using two way binding, and this is as expected. but the local category variable of openModal() method also got changed. Any help will be appreciated If anyone need more code, please let me know.

[image]